# Running total per group in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are 3 columns in my table: Group, Date and Money.

```
Group    Day    Money    Column4 (Does not exist yet)
 A        1     $100     $100
 B        2     $500     $500
 A        3     $-150    $-50
 B        3     $900     $1400
```

What I'm trying to do is to create column 4 which is essentially a running total for each group. The running total for Group A is (100, 100-150=50).

Is this possible in SQL Server 2008? My code to get the first 3 columns is below:

```
Select [Group], [Day], sum(money) as [Money]
From Table_Name
Group by [Group], [Day]
```

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/grouped-running-totals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is with cumulative sum.  Perhaps it is time to update to a more recent version of SQL Server?

In SQL Server 2008, you can use `apply` or a correlated subquery:

```
Select [Group], [Day], sum(money) as [Money],
       (select sum(t2.money)
        from table_name t2
        where t.group = t2.group and t2.day <= t.day
       ) as Column4
From Table_Name t
Group by [Group], [Day];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function `sum` to find the cummulative sum:

```
select 
    t.*,
    sum(Money) over (partition by [group] order by [Day]) col4
from your_table t;
```

So your query becomes:

```
select t.*,
    sum([Money]) over (
        partition by [group] order by [Day]
        ) col4
from (
    select [Group],
        [Day],
        sum(money) as [Money]
    from Table_Name
    group by [Group],
        [Day]
    ) t;
```

Comment: This is only possible on SQL Server 2012 and higher